# Oracle Object-Relational - How to get REF(SELF) in PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to select the REF(SELF) in a method of an object. For example:

```sql
CREATE TYPE SOMETYPE_TY AS OBJECT(
  attr1 VARCHAR2(20),
  attr2 DATE,
  MEMBER PROCEDURE AddSomething(A1 VARCHAR2, A2 VARCHAR2)
) NOT FINAL;
```

How can I get the REF(SELF) in a method, like the following?

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY SOMETYPE_TY AS 
MEMBER PROCEDURE AddSomething(A1 VARCHAR2, A2 VARCHAR2) AS
  some_ref REF SOMETYPE_TY;
BEGIN
  SELECT REF(SELF) INTO some_ref FROM DUAL;
END AddSomething;
END;
/
```

I tried with the DUAL table but it tells me `ORA-24344: success with compilation error`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot. A `REF` is a pointer to a row in an object-derived table; it is not a pointer to an object.

From the [`REF` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions127.htm):

> `REF` takes as its argument a correlation variable (table alias) associated with a row of an object table or an object view. A `REF` value is returned for the object instance that is bound to the variable or row.

To be able to get a `REF`erence to an object you need to put that object into a table and then get the `REF`erence to the table row.